# where clause filing when two columns are used to compare

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

where condition failing if one of the conditions is specified and it does not seems to be wrong because i am specifying AND operator but i am not 100% sure on it and one point, only 1 value willbe active, either activity_id or assignmentrecordID

Here is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
              assignmentRecordId,
              activityId,
              activityType,
              activityTitle,
              activityDescription,
              
FROM dbo.Activity
WHERE ((@assignmentRecordId IS NULL OR assignmentRecordID = @assignmentRecordId) -- failing
  AND (@activity_id IS NULL OR activity_id = @activity_id)) -- this and he above is failing
  AND (@Search = '' OR (@Search != '' AND    (
                                    assignmentRecordId LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
                                OR    activityNumber LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
                                OR    activityTitle LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
  )))
```

the `--` one is failing because if i use OR, it gets all record, at one of time, it will either be assignmentrecordid or activity_id, but cannot be both,
if i use and, it does not get any results what am i doing wrong here

and everything described in where clause can be `NULL`

Comment: What you have here is known as a "[Catch-all](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)" or "[Kitchen Sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)" query; you should have a read of the linked articles.

Comment: YOu really need to give us some sample data and expected results here; `@assignmentRecordId IS NULL OR assignmentRecordID` is the correct syntax.

Comment: In these cases it's sometimes better to, rather than try to have one execution plan fit-all, have several execution plans that are optimised for the specific criteria either by dynamically building and executing a sql statement or by calling one of several stored procedures.

Comment: i am tryi8ng to be simple here, if one of the values here is not nul, search on that value basically the assignmentrecordid or activity_id, now the search section is the one where the search is executed from datatables and it can pass anything and if i have 3 columns displaying and any one value is passed in search along with assignmentrecordid or activity_id, if it finds, it should show else no

Comment: @will read the articles. What you try to do results in bad execution plans and slow queries. The query ends up being so complex it's hard to read and maintain for no benefit. Finally, `activityNumber LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'` can't use indexes which means the server has to scan the entire table.

Comment: @will the reason for the bad execution plans is that queries are compiled into execution plans the first time they're sent to the server, using the parameters passed in that execution. Subsequent executions use that plan. If `@assignmentRecordId` the query won't try to use any indexes on `assignmentRecordID` because it doesn't have to. If you try to search with a specific `assignmentRecordID` later on, it would still not use any indexes.

Comment: @will if on the other hand, the first execution uses a non-null parameter, the server may create a plan using an index seek that will be used even if the next query requires no filtering.

Comment: `it will either be assignmentrecordid or activity_id, but cannot be both,` that's the XOR operator - it's true if only one of the options is true, otherwise false. SQL, the language, doesn't have a XOR operator and most databases don't have a XOR operator either. It's rarely needed and can be emulated using `NOT`, `AND` and `OR`

Comment: Is this question still active? If so, would you post some sample data and sample parameter values? Also, you're using NULL for IDs and '' for Search, you should make sure you aren't accidentally getting them mixed up in parameters or data, because that could cause what you're describing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This type of query is called a [Kitchen Sink Query](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

You should build and execute a dynamic SQL query for the parameters specified.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)  = '
SELECT
  assignmentRecordId,
  activityId,
  activityType,
  activityTitle,
  activityDescription            
FROM dbo.Activity a
WHERE 1=1
';

IF @assignmentRecordId IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql += '
  AND assignmentRecordID = @assignmentRecordId';

IF @activity_id IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql += '
  AND activity_id = @activity_id';

IF ISNULL(@Search, '') <> ''
    SET @sql += '
  AND (
       assignmentRecordId LIKE ''%'' + @Search + ''%''
    OR activityNumber     LIKE ''%'' + @Search + ''%''
    OR activityTitle      LIKE ''%'' + @Search + ''%''
  )';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
  N'@assignmentRecordId int,
    @activity_id int,
    @Search nvarchar(1000)',
  @assignmentRecordId = @assignmentRecordId,
  @activity_id = @activity_id,
  @Search = @Search;
```

Note how the actual parameters are still passed through and not injected.

Depending on requirements you may want `ELSE IF @activity_id IS NOT NULL` instead

Comment: `assignmentRecordId LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'` will result in SQL injection. Instead of escaping quotes, the script could be rewritten as `assignmentRecordId LIKE @search...` and the wildcards should be added when passing the parameter in `sp_executesql`, eg `@Search = '%' +@Search + '%'`

Comment: Are there any other issues with this code? I'd love to know what the downvotes are for.

Comment: I *up*voted. The problem is in the question, not this answer. Apart from the catch-all, it seems there's an XOR relation between assignmentRecordId and activity_id.

Comment: I mention that on the last line also. Yeah I guess it wasn't you, just wondering what it could be.